# window.print - what setting makes the browser print a url

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

When I use the window.print() javascript function on a website, it adds a url in print mode. For example the link **Stichting Rondom Mantelzorg** with the following underlying html code

```html
<a href="?q=node/838">Stichting Rondom Mantelzorg</a>
```

is printed (with window.print()) as: "Stichting Rondom Mantelzorg (?q=node/838)". 
Can someone explain me where this might come from?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends up on browser . Browser automatically adds the url at header of the page if you print. you can check for page setup in your browser and change it accordingly. It has no relation with window.print() , it is browser's functionality.

Comment: Actually I'm not talking about the url at the header of a page, but about the urls on the page itself. See for example the print version of [link](http://www.denhaag.nl). Every url on the page is printed while on the print version of this page no url is shown.